# How does village expansion work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to build my own village, and for that I need to have sharp knowledge of village mechanics that the online documentation does not provide sufficiently.

I know that points of interests (beds, job blocks, bells) in the area of the village expands its boundary, but I don't know how it works exactly.

If there is 1 bell, and 1 bed 20 blocks away, what will be the result? Does a new point of interest increase the total radius of the village, or does it create a new area of 32 blocks by 32 blocks? Will the village now be 52 blocks by 52 blocks or 32 blocks by 52 blocks?

Comment: I don't know if anyone is going to be able to answer this, so if no one does you can always try decompiling Minecraft and looking at the source code, Java isn't anything too different from the normal C structure most programming languages have so as long as you know some kind of normal programming language it shouldn't be too difficult to read, although what you are asking for may be buried away somewhere. Try looking in the world generation or structures types of files. - Also, if you're building your own village can't you just take an example from a normal world, or is it randomly generated?

Comment: Alternatively they could try testing out their questions in-game on a Creative mode world, and see what works and what doesn't in context to what they're wanting to build. It would possibly be much more reasonably do-able than digging through the source code.

Comment: @Penguin I am creating a very special village. It is located in a submarine rift, which makes it very different from flat villages on the surface so I can't just copy a naturally generated village. I might consider decompiling the game, I didn't know that was possible, I just need to learn how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: @BlueTangsRock in-game testing on a flat world is a great idea and I have done it, however it's still a very long, fastidious and imprecise way of understanding village mechanics. Digging in the code might be a long and fastidious task too, but perhaps it will help me sharpening my knwoledge in a way in-game testing cannot. (also, the company I just joined does use some Java so digging some Java should help me professionally :D)

Comment: Here is how I decompiled Mineraft: [http://www.modcoderpack.com/](http://www.modcoderpack.com/). You will also probably need to watch a youtube tutorial to go with it

Comment: @Penguin tahnk  you kind sir :)